# Android Studio 1.0.2 “Projects Template” can't get to work

Tags: android, android-studio, code-reuse

On Ubuntu 14.04 LTS, 64 bit.

Set a “Template” at:

Android Studio Main Menu - > Tools - > Save Project as Template. . .

Click “OK”.

Get Pop up:
Titled: “Template Created”
Message: “Test_Template” was successfully created it's available now in Project Wizard”

PROBLEM.
Using the New Project Wizard, no access the “Test_Template” that I made.

Checked for “Test_Template” at “Android Studio Main Menu - > Tools - > Manage Project Templates. . ..” “Test_Template” Shows.

Checked Android Studio Main Menu - > File - > Setting . . . -  > File and Code Templates” Can not find “Test_Template”. Check other sections in “Setting . . .” found nothing obvious.

Tried the different combinations of setting at “Android Studio Main Menu - > Tools - > Save Project as Template. . . “ Hoping that one of the possible combinations would make “Test_Template” show up in the New Project Wizard.

Checked “Project Structure” - > Dependencies - > Green Plus Sign” No apparent way to set to a “Template”.

Check StackOverFlow, Google, Android Studio bug tracker and a book on Android Studio found nothing useful in the IDE. Best found was blog on how to hack the XML that better than year old. The Official Android site, however was outdated to be polite.

I hope I am doing something stupid because “Template” at the module level would be very helpful.

Thank You in advance, Mark.

Comment: This is unimplemented for Android Studio. You can track the bug at https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=81741

Answer (score -1):

Not found "Tools> Save the Project Template ..." but
"Tools> Save the Template File ..."

When rescued a "Util.java" file as a template, found again by visiting:
File> New> "Util" to reuse it.